# Google Cloud Speech API slow after becoming GA (generally available)

Tags: android, google-speech-api

I've an application that implements speech recognition for a container repair facility; it's based on gRPC async recognition, and has always worked well with good transcription times (the audio to be transcripted is generally short, from 1 to 8 seconds).
The application has not been used for some time, and now that the Speech API has became GA, I had to udate it because with the old library I always obtain an UNAUTHENTICATED error opening che communication channel.
The problem is that the transcription time has became high, compared to the v1beta1; for a single word transcription ("Lista", for example) it takes no less than 3 seconds, but the standard is 5 seconds, somewhat unacceptable from the customer's point of view. From the logcat, where you can see the time taken (in this particular case 8 seconds, from requestObserver.onComplete event to the transcription) I also see some strange warnings, not generated from my code :

```
07-18 11:09:32.705 9872-10459/it.sia.contrepair D/it.sia.contrepair: src, wPos=25096,rPos=24576,toRead=520
07-18 11:09:32.705 9872-10459/it.sia.contrepair D/it.sia.contrepair: src.requestObserver.onComplete()
07-18 11:09:32.706 9872-10459/it.sia.contrepair D/it.sia.contrepair: src.dataSendThread.finishLatch.await
07-18 11:09:32.714 9872-10346/it.sia.contrepair D/it.sia.contrepair: Stop read runnable
07-18 11:09:40.285 9872-10606/it.sia.contrepair W/UnsafeUtil: platform method missing - proto runtime falling back to safer methods: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getByte [long]
07-18 11:09:40.286 9872-10606/it.sia.contrepair W/UnsafeUtil: platform method missing - proto runtime falling back to safer methods: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getByte [class java.lang.Object, long]
07-18 11:09:40.287 9872-10606/it.sia.contrepair W/UnsafeUtil: copyMemory is missing from platform - proto runtime falling back to safer methods.
07-18 11:09:40.769 9872-10606/it.sia.contrepair D/it.sia.contrepair: results {
                                                                       alternatives {
                                                                         transcript: "lista"
                                                                         confidence: 0.93588203
                                                                       }
                                                                       alternatives {
                                                                         transcript: "Lista"
                                                                       }
                                                                       alternatives {
                                                                         transcript: "vista"
                                                                       }
                                                                       is_final: true
                                                                     }
07-18 11:09:42.706 9872-10459/it.sia.contrepair D/it.sia.contrepair: src.dataSendThread.finishLatch exited
07-18 11:09:42.706 9872-10459/it.sia.contrepair D/it.sia.contrepair: src.shutting down channel
07-18 11:09:42.713 9872-10459/it.sia.contrepair D/it.sia.contrepair: src.channel shutted down
```

The warnings doesn't always happen, as you can see from this second logcat excerpt:

```
07-18 11:10:26.404 9872-11328/it.sia.contrepair D/it.sia.contrepair: src.requestObserver.onComplete()
07-18 11:10:26.404 9872-11328/it.sia.contrepair D/it.sia.contrepair: src.dataSendThread.finishLatch.await
07-18 11:10:26.413 9872-11233/it.sia.contrepair D/it.sia.contrepair: Stop read runnable
07-18 11:10:29.853 9872-11431/it.sia.contrepair D/it.sia.contrepair: results {
                                                                       alternatives {
                                                                         transcript: "annulla"
                                                                         confidence: 0.9913793
                                                                       }
                                                                       is_final: true
                                                                     }
07-18 11:10:29.947 9872-9888/it.sia.contrepair D/it.sia.contrepair: onStart
07-18 11:10:29.952 9872-11431/it.sia.contrepair D/it.sia.contrepair: src.responseObserver.onCompleted()
07-18 11:10:29.953 9872-11328/it.sia.contrepair D/it.sia.contrepair: src.dataSendThread.finishLatch exited
07-18 11:10:29.953 9872-11328/it.sia.contrepair D/it.sia.contrepair: src.shutting down channel
07-18 11:10:29.954 9872-11328/it.sia.contrepair D/it.sia.contrepair: src.channel shutted down
```

This is Android Studio dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/dsp-collection.jar')
    compile files('libs/javaFlacEncoder-0.3.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-auth:1.4.0'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.4.0'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
    compile 'com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.7.1'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'
    compile 'com.google.api.grpc:grpc-google-cloud-speech-v1:0.1.13'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'
}
```

Has anyone developed an application using Google Cloud Speech and encountered the same problems ?

Thanks.
Rodolfo.